# django передать переменную из шаблона во views

Tags: python, django

никак не получается передать переменную(user.username) из шаблона во views, выбрал простой вариант передать через запрос, ошибок не выдает, но и переменная не приходит:

template:

```
    <form action="{% url 'cabinet' %}?user.username={{user.username}}" method="post">
        
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <button type="submit" class="w-50 btn btn-primary btn-block">create search</button>
  </form>
```

фрагмент views:

```
def add_search(request):

    username = request.GET.get('user.username')

    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        form = AddSearch(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
Global_Users.objects.filter(name=username).update(**form.cleaned_data)
else:
    form = AddSearch()
return render(request, 'webface/add_search.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: Почему у вас вьюха называется `add_search`, а в url формы написано `cabinet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пользователь авторизированный его юзернэйм можешь получить через request.

```py
def add_search(request):

    username = request.user.username
```

Comment: то что нужно, это сработало для меня! а  скажите пожалуйста, таким методом можно передать пользователя только во views? допустим если мне нужно передать его так же в другой app или скрипт в этом же проекте?